# Как обработать панику и вернуть 500 http GO

Tags: golang, http

Пишу сервер на GO. Столкнулся с необходимостью обработки паник. Если где-то случается паника то сервер ничего не отвечает. Нужно чтобы вернул 500 код.

Намутил пока что такой код (сильно упрощённый и удалённый от реального):

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"
    "fmt"
    "log"
)

// Функция, которая обрабатывает наш запрос, вызывается из main
func view(res http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    // запишем статус ответа 200
    res.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)

    /* допустим для определения контента нам нужно выполнить
       какой-либо код, в нём возникает паника */
    var test map[string]string
    test["hello"] = "world"

    res.Write([]byte("Hello, it's main page!"))
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Starting serve on :8000")

    // ждём запроса по адресу "/"
    http.HandleFunc("/", func(res http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
        // запускаем отложенную функцию для отслеживания паник
        defer func() {
            /* если произошла паника, то вывести ошибку в консоль
               и выернуть http 500 */
            if err := recover(); err != nil {
                log.Println("Panic occurred:", err)
                // http пакет ругается здесь, об этом ниже
                res.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
            }
        }()

        // функция которая обрабатывает запрос
        view(res, req)
    })

    // Запустить прослушивание сокета
    http.ListenAndServe(":8000", nil)
}
```

Комменты написал, думаю понятно где что. Если что пишите комментарии, добавлю больше объяснений. Суть в том, что при таком раскладе `http` пакет ругается на то, что я пытаюсь перезаписать уже записанный 200 код и не делает этого. Да самое банальное, это устанавливать код ответа и контент в самом конце функции, после всех действий. Но я через некоторое время могу это забыть, когда буду писать вьюшки или кто-то другой может редактировать мой код. Его поведение в таком случае будет очень неочевидным, поэтому это мне больше напоминает какой-то костыль. Есть способы сделать это лучше?

Answer (score 0):

Нужно пользоваться функцией [http.Error](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Error)

Обработка ошибок в вашем примере может выглядеть вот так:

```go
            if err := recover(); err != nil {
                log.Println("Panic occurred:", err)
                // http пакет ругается здесь, об этом ниже
                http.Error(res, "Internal error: "+err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
            }
```